# Use jquery to remove a div with no children

Tags: jquery, css

How can I use jquery to remove a SPECIFIC div that has no children (at least no children that isn't whitespace). E.g.

```
<div id="outer">
    some content
    <div id="removeme"> 


    </div>
    some more content
</div>
```

Want to completely remove the div with id="removeme".

Answer (score 50, accepted):

To remove the element with `id` equal to `removeme`:

```
$("#removeme").remove();
```

To remove the element with `id` equal to `removeme` only if it is empty:

```
$("#removeme:empty").remove();
```

To remove all empty `<div>`s:

```
$("div:empty").remove();
```

**EDIT:** If it's not empty, but has whitespace:

```
if($.trim($("#removeme").text()) == "") {
  $("#removeme").remove();
}
```

Comment: I think he's just referring that div by giving it an id, but he actually wants to remove all empty divs on the page... thats just my guess.

Comment: No, Ben is correct. Want to remove a specific div if its empty

Comment: hmmm, actually this doesnt work. empty whitespace counted as children?

Comment: I would guess that :empty will work if you change the div markup to be self-closing: <div id="removeme"/>

Comment: I'm sure it would, but if i could change the div to be self closing I wouldn't need to remove via jquery later :)

Comment: Then try :not(:parent).  :empty isn't working because it thinks there is some inner text in that div.

Comment: Tried $('#removeme:not(:parent)').remove() - no good, same problem as :empty I presume

Comment: No, that removed the node even when it did have non-whitespace children

Comment: Okay, last try before I give up.

Comment: Congratulations. Got it on the last go! Thanks Ben.

Comment: if only wants to remove or change the id what we can do? not entire div

Answer (score 8):

I went with:

```
$('#outer > div').filter(function (index) { 
    return $(this).children().length < 1; 
}).remove();
```

This says:

- give me all the div children of #outer
- use filter to get rid of any which have child nodes
- remove anything we still have selected

Sadly, this will remove the div if it contains text, which is probably not what the original poster would have wanted. Plain text doesn't count as a child.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use:

$('div:empty').remove();

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/empty

Comment: so $('div#removeme:empty').remove() gets just that node?

Comment: Yes, only if it has no child elements or inner text.

Comment: and if it has inner text (albeit whitespace)?

Comment: then no. It won't select it or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a selector that ignores text nodes, so this is the quickest/dirtiest code snippet I could come up with.

```
$("#header").each(function() { 
    if($(this).children().length < 1) 
        $(this).remove() 
});
```

Comment: could you explain this for us?

Comment: Here, we're selecting a div that is not a parent. (does not have child elements)

See the jQuery selectors documentation: http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

Comment: i don't want to select and remove EVERY div that has no children

Comment: You asked how to use jquery to remove a div that has no children.  In that case, just use $("#removeme").remove()

Comment: that doesnt look like its checking to see whether is has children

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
$('div#outer div:empty').remove();
```

It will remove all the empty divs inside the div#outer node

Answer (score 0):

Here is if empty with children then you can point at children and then remove a parent, 
this dont look at whitespaces it just remove if empty

so like; if li is empty it removes #removeme

```
if (!$("#tabs ul li").length) $('#tabs').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove parent if it doesn't have a child with specific class

```
$('.parentClass:not(:has(.childClass))').remove();
```