# how to permanenlty remove a div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I was trying to remove a certain div element from my HTML using jQuery I saw this [Use jquery to remove a div with no children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527246/use-jquery-to-remove-a-div-with-no-children), the jquery remove methods work perfectly fine but the problem is of Persistence,

Actually i want to permanently remove that div for that person, i was storing this in cookies but the problem is this remove method doesn't actually remove the code so when I parse through the code to store it using the cookies i store the removed code also. is there any way i can achieve a permanent removal for particular person??

Thanks
Pranay

Since many people are confused here is what I was trying to achieve http://virtser.net/inettuts/ this was demo of http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/inettuts-with-cookies/ where he extended functionality of his code by adding Cokkiee support to retain the widget positions.

This code works fine for moving editing and collapse or expanding widget. It saves everything in cookie but for delete this does't work. It delete the widget but when i try to save it in cookie since the div element is present in code it does't save the deleted item

Comment: Totally confusing what you are trying to do. a code example may help clarify it. If you want not to show certain part of html on some condition, when you hide it you may need to do an ajax call to switch the condition

Comment: it sounds like you may want to use a database and some backend scripting. cookies expire and can be deleted. this would also allow you to (if desired) not print the div in the first place when outputting the page from the server. do you know any server side languages?

Comment: As per dqhendricks, storing code in cookies is almost certainly the wrong approach.

Comment: I can use client side storage of HTML5 for storing the configuration but how to detect the deleted element??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery isn't ideal for permanent removal of elements from a page as it's stateless.

Its a client side wrapper for javascript to interact with the DOM.  While in theory, you can have it remove elements from the DOM based on readable cookies a particular user may have after a page has loaded, it's not ideal when server side coding could handle this without much effort.

Answer (score 1):

to remove it permanently you have to use serverside language for example [php](http://php.net)

Answer (score 0):

You could revert the process and *add* the DIV for specific users instead, leaving the data in the .js instead.

Answer (score 0):

To remove DIV "permanently" you have to use serverside lang. The logic is simple:

1. Remove DIV from HTML
2. Save some info about user and removed DIV in cookies
3. In serverside script you have to get cookie and check did user disable any div or not. If he did your script should skip DIV generation