# I want to remove a div permanently using jquery cookie plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a notification bar at the top of the page that notify's the user about some features of the page, the notification bar is not on every page. Now I want to remove the notification bar, permanently if the user clicks on **"Don't show me again"**.

I have looked into different solutions, but none of them seem to be working for me.

I found jquery cookie plugin and tried that, but no success. 
Then I found this [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565295/how-to-permanenlty-remove-a-div-using-jquery), is it true?

This is my view:

```
<div class="scrollup" id="message">
    <p>Here goes some lines of text blah blah.....
        <button class="btn-primary">Don't show me again</button> 
        <a class="alert-close">x</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

This is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function (c) {
    $('.alert-close').on('click', function (c) {
        $(this).parent().fadeOut('slow', function (c) {});
    });
});
$.cookie('remove', 'value');
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("button").click(function (e) {
        $("#message").$.removeCookie('remove', null);
        alert("lalalsk");
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: Without assuming it is either wrong or good.. have you tested the code before asking this question? As your question indicates you haven't.

Comment: @larssy1: I tried the code but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the bar permanently on every browser and PC the user uses you would unfortunately need to set up that logic from server side code.
Cookies only lie in the browser the user is currently using and they have the ability to remove cookies whenever they like.

Why don't you create the message with javascript (either with DOM manipulation or planting HTML within an existing DIV) and show it only if the particular cookie is not present. 
That way whenever the user accesses that page as long as the cookie is present the popup message won't appear.