# Using jquery how can I remove a DIV if it's contents are empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to remove the following empty div using jquery.

The following div is output sometimes without content inside it. For display reasons I need to remove it when it's empty.

```
<div class="field-group-format group_call_to_action_aside div group-call-to-action-aside box yellow speed-fast effect-none"></div>
```

Thoughts?

I've been trying the following and variations of it, but have't had any luck.

Comment: Are you only targeting divs with that exact set of classes?

Comment: Giving a `div` the class `div` is kind of redundant.

Comment: Actually I am targeting any empty div with the class field-group-format

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works, **assuming** you don't have other `div.group_call_to_action_aside` that you want to keep:

```
if ($('.group_call_to_action_aside').is(':empty')) { 
    $('.group_call_to_action_aside').remove();
}
```

Note: I've styled the `div`, so you can see a brief flash of it before the js takes effect.  but you won't see this when you do it because the `div` is empty. ;-)

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/L8dwn/

**EDIT**

Yes, as per your commment, you can also do this

`$('.group_call_to_action_aside:empty').remove();`

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/L8dwn/1/

Comment: Is there a reason I can't just use...
$(".field-group-format:empty").remove();
by itself?

Comment: @Bryan: In fact, that would be the *preferred* way to do it.

Comment: @Bryan Casler. No reason why not.  Modified my answer.  Agreed @patrick dw.

Comment: @Jason: Assuming there's more than one element matching the selector, then in your first example, if *any* element matching is empty, the `if()` will evaluate to `true`, and *all* the elements will be removed. I'd remove that first solution. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/L8dwn/2/)

Comment: @patrick dw.  Yes, thanks.  I wrote *assuming you don't have other empty `div.group_call_to_action_aside` that you want to keep*.  What I meant was other `div`s period.  I've fixed the sentence.  Thx

Answer (score 3):

To remove the element with `id` equal to `removeme`:

```
$("#removeme").remove();
```

To remove the element with `id` equal to `removeme` only if it is empty:

```
$("#removeme:empty").remove();
```

To remove all empty `<div>`s:

```
$("div:empty").remove();
```

**EDIT:** If it's not empty, but has whitespace:

```
if($.trim($("#removeme").text()) == "") {
  $("#removeme").remove();
}
```

Reference: [Use jquery to remove a div with no children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527246/use-jquery-to-remove-a-div-with-no-children)