# Clear dynamically generated images

Tags: jquery, image, dynamic, generated

This is my current [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gbzsR/8/).I am trying to load images dynamically and now I would like to know how do I remove all the images from all the pages with a click of button.

Here is my code:

```
     $(function () {
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({

            dataType: 'json',
            done: function (e, data) {
                $("#demo5").paginate({
                    count: pageNumber,
                    start: 1,
                    display: Math.min(7, pageNumber),
                    border: true,
                    border_color: '#fff',
                    text_color: '#fff',
                    background_color: 'black',
                    border_hover_color: '#ccc',
                    text_hover_color: '#000',
                    background_hover_color: '#fff',
                    images: false,
                    mouse: 'press',
                    onChange: function (page) {
                        $('#paginationdemo ._current').removeClass('_current').hide();
                        $('#p' + page).addClass('_current').show();
                    }
                });
                $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {

                    if (imagesInPage >= imagesPerPage) {
                        imagesInPage = 1;
                        pageNumber += 1;
                        divPage = $('<div/>', { id: "p" + pageNumber }).addClass('pagedemo').hide().appendTo(pagesContainer);
                    } else {
                        imagesInPage += 1;
                    }
                    var src = 'Uploads/' + file.name;
                    $('<img>', { src: src, href: src, "class": 'LoadclickImage', align: 'left', width:'87', height:'60' }).appendTo(divPage);

                });

            }
        });
```

This is my div structure:

```
<div id="paginationdemo" class="demo">
    <div id="pagesContainer">
        <div id="p1" class="pagedemo _current"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="demo5"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

$(".LoadclickImage").remove();

Look up `.remove()` in the [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/).  Also consider `.detach()`.

Comment: @Michael-Thank you so much.It worked well and is there any other way for the pages to remove.

Comment: `remove()` would probably be better as the images aren't being re-attached again later. http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossman-Yes,I just now had a view at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527246/use-jquery-to-remove-a-div-with-no-children and I am dilemma that how do I remove the appended pages.