# Remove parent if it doesn't have a child with specific class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a code like this:

```
<div class='parent one'>
  <div class='yes'></div>
  <div class='yes'></div>
  <div class='yes'></div>
</div>

<div class='parent two'>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class='parent three'>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class='yes'></div>
</div>
```

How do I remove `.parent.two` because it doesn't have any child with `.yes`? What I've tried so far and it didn't work:

```
$('.parent div:not(.yes)').remove();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69274468/7186739

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `:not` with `:has`:

```js
$(() => $('.parent:not(:has(.yes))').remove())
```

```css
.parent{ background: orange; height: 100px; width: 100px; margin: 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent one'>
  <div class='yes'>Child of one</div>
  <div class='yes'>Child of one</div>
  <div class='yes'>Child of one</div>
</div>

<div class='parent two'>
  <div>Child of two</div>
  <div>Child of two</div>
  <div>Child of two</div>
</div>

<div class='parent three'>
  <div>Child of three</div>
  <div>Child of three</div>
  <div class='yes'>Child of three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a selector as a combination of `:not` and `:has` and then use `remove` method. So this will select all elements with `.parent` class that do not have child element with `.yes` class.

```
$('.parent:not(:has(.yes))')
```

```js
$('.parent:not(:has(.yes))').remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent one'>
  <div class='yes'>one</div>
  <div class='yes'></div>
  <div class='yes'></div>
</div>

<div class='parent two'>
  <div>two</div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class='parent three'>
  <div>three</div>
  <div></div>
  <div class='yes'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

this is how you can do with vanilla js

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".parent").forEach(ele => {
  if (ele.querySelector(".yes") == null) {
    ele.remove();
  }
})

//for checking
document.querySelectorAll(".parent").forEach(ele => {
  console.log(ele)
})
```

```html
<div class='parent one'>
  <div class='yes'></div>
  <div class='yes'></div>
  <div class='yes'></div>
</div>

<div class='parent two'>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class='parent three'>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class='yes'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that in many ways. The basic approaches are :

Directly selecting :

`$('.parent.two').remove();`

Selecting on the basis of it's index :

`$('.parent:eq(1)').remove();`

On the basis of presence of `.yes` element as child :

`$('.parent div').not('.parent .yes').parent().remove();`

Answer (score 0):

Check the `.innerHTML` of each parent `div` to see if a child with that text exists and remove the parent if not.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("div.parent").forEach(function(parentDiv){
  if(!parentDiv.innerHTML.includes('<div class="yes">')){
    parentDiv.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<div class='parent one'>1
  <div class='yes'></div>
  <div class='yes'></div>
  <div class='yes'></div>
</div>

<div class='parent two'>2
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class='parent three'>3
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class='yes'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Alternatively, wouldn't it be good to use `parentDiv.querySelector(".yes").length`?

Comment: You can do it many different ways. I'm just showing one here.